# Delete element from array

Tags: java, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing an element from an Array (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642897/removing-an-element-from-an-array-java)

Is there a way I can get  rid of some elements in an array.
for instance, if i have this array

```
int testArray[] = {0,2,0,3,0,4,5,6}
```

Is there a "fast" way to get rid of the elements that equal 0

```
int resultArray[] = {2,3,4,5,6}
```

I tried this function but I got lost using Lists

```
public int[] getRidOfZero(int []s){
   List<> result=new ArrayList<>();
   for(int i=0; i<s.length; i++){
     if(s[i]<0){
       int temp = s[i];
       result.add(temp);
     }
   }
   return result.toArray(new int[]);
}
```

Comment: Because this question specifically asks about removing elements in the middle of an array, it is really not the same thing - voting to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java arrays can't be resized. You need to create a new array.

Count the non-zero elements in the array. Create a new array that size. Copy the elements from the old to the new array, skipping over zero elements.

You can do this with lists. Your best bet is to create a list of Integers; add non-zero elements to it; then use toArray to create an array from the list.

Answer (score 1):

You're quite close, but:

- Your generics were messed up (`List<>` is syntactically invalid)
- Your comparison was only adding the element if it was less than zero (rather than adding it if it was not equal to zero)
- <s>You were calling the wrong [`toArray()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29) method.</s>Because `ints` are primitives, you have to turn the list back into an array yourself.

---

```
public int[] getRidOfZero(int[] s) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
    for (int i : s) {
        if (i != 0) {
            result.add(i);
        }
    }

    int[] toReturn = new int[result.size()];
    for (int i=0; i<result.size(); i++) {
        toReturn[i] = result.get(i);
    }

    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: Im guessing here temp would have to be an Integer object

Comment: @Julio: sorry, that's a typo on my part. Fixed.

Comment: toArray returns an Object[] array, your method returns int[]. Primitives make this more painful.

Comment: @Julio - no, neither `temp` nor `i` need to be an `Integer` object, thanks to the magic of Java [autoboxing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html).

Comment: @Yishai: ngh... you're right. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're starting with an array, you'll need to create a new array and copy the items from the old array, excluding the zeros.

If you remove a bunch of zeros at once, this is going to be fast.

Otherwise, you'll need to begin with the doubly-linked [LinkedList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

LinkedList has an iterator that allows you to move along the list and remove elements, which will be a constant-time operation.