# How to remove elements from an array in java even if we have to iterate over array or can we do it directly?

Tags: java, arrays

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do I remove objects from an Array in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112503/how-do-i-remove-objects-from-an-array-in-java)
>   [Removing an element from an Array (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642897/removing-an-element-from-an-array-java)

```
listOfNames = new String [] {"1","2","3","4"}; //
String [] l = new String [listOfNames.length-1];
for(int i=0; i<listOfNames.length-1; i++)    //removing the first element
   l[i] = listOfNames[i+1];
```

// can this work , Is there a better way ? to remove certain elements from an array in this case the first one .

Comment: Java?.......... please use a short, significant title and state the actual question in the text.

Comment: If this is not for homework where you need to use arrays, have a look at [Collections](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html), especially [Lists](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112503/how-do-i-remove-objects-from-an-array-in-java

Comment: Oh see, I missed `java` in the title because I did not bother to read it (too long). Tag questions appropriately. More users will view it then.

Comment: Why was this closed?  The problem is different than the possible duplicates, as this is trying to remove an element at the end, rather than any element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a `for` loop :

```
String[] array = new String[]{"12","23","34"};
java.util.List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
list.remove(0);
String[] new_array = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

**Tip**
  If you can, stick with `List`, you'll have more *flexibility*.

Comment: `Arrays.asList()` does not support `remove` (or add).

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] listOfNames = new String [] {"1","2","3","4"};
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(listOfNames));
list.remove(0);
String[] array = list.toArray(array);
```