# How to remove specific value from string array in java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing an element from an Array (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642897/removing-an-element-from-an-array-java)

How to remove specific String array value for example

`String[] str_array = {"item1","item2","item3"};`

i want to remove "item2" from str_array pls help me i want output like

`String[] str_array = {"item1","item3"};`

Comment: You needed to copy to a new array if you want the length to reduce also. Use ArrayList if you want dynamic size array

Comment: You have to iterate the Array and compare your value

Comment: i know remove value from arraylist we use "list.remove()" but i need is there any property to remove string in string array

Comment: @Vicky: No. There is no such property.

Comment: The arrays by themselves don't have these methods. If you want to do it in a single and effective line, you should follow PeterLawrey's advice: http://stackoverflow.com/a/644719/1065197

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I would do it as follows:

```
String[] str_array = {"item1","item2","item3"};
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str_array));
list.remove("item2");
str_array = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: Inefficient compared to use of `System.arraycopy`, especially when used multiple times.

Comment: @Vulcan, thanks for your comment, would you mind updating my answer to show how to use System.arraycopy here? Thanks.

Comment: @Vikdor I'll post an answer that uses it, one moment.

Comment: @Vikdor Sorry for the delay, got distracted with something.  I've posted the answer though.

Comment: this really useful... This answer helped me loads

Answer (score 7):

If you *must* use arrays, `System.arraycopy` is the most efficient, scalable solution.  However, if you must remove one element from an array several times, you should use an implementation of List rather than an array.

The following utilizes `System.arraycopy` in order to achieve the desired effect.

```
public static Object[] remove(Object[] array, Object element) {
    if (array.length > 0) {
        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i].equals(element)) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (index >= 0) {
            Object[] copy = (Object[]) Array.newInstance(array.getClass()
                    .getComponentType(), array.length - 1);
            if (copy.length > 0) {
                System.arraycopy(array, 0, copy, 0, index);
                System.arraycopy(array, index + 1, copy, index, copy.length - index);
            }
            return copy;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Also, you can increase the method's efficiency if you know that your array consists of only `Comparable` objects. You can use `Arrays.sort` to sort them before passing them through the `remove` method, modified to use `Arrays.binarySearch` to find index rather than a for loop, raising that portion of the method's efficiency from O(n) to O(nlogn).

Comment: It's not very nice to get an `Object[]` back when you want a `String[]`. [`Array.newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int%29) lets you construct an array of arbitrary type.

Comment: @gustafc Good point. The downside to that is slightly slower execution time though.

Comment: It's also worth noting that *O(n log n)* isn't necessarily faster than *O(n)* as Big O only tells you how the cost of handling *n+1* elements is compared to handling *n* elements with the same algorithm. The constant cost associated with sorting may well outweigh the benefits of binary search (especially for small arrays).

Comment: `Array.newInstance` *might* be slower, but it is not necessarily so. HotSpot can optimize it to be just as fast as a regular array instantiation in most cases. Either way, you end up with a more robust and correct program.

Comment: Ah, that's good.  It was slightly slower in a small test I just conducted (average of 0.40ms for new Object[x], and average 0.45ms for Array.newInstance), but the margin is so small that I'd say it's irrelevant and may not even exist.

Comment: Indeed. Also, if that part of the code becomes a bottleneck, arrays probably aren't the most appropriate data structure for your program.

Answer (score 4):

Other Option is to copy array to other array accept than remove item.

```
 public static String[] removeItemFromArray(String[] input, String item) {
    if (input == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (input.length <= 0) {
        return input;
    } else {
        String[] output = new String[input.length - 1];
        int count = 0;
        for (String i : input) {
            if (!i.equals(item)) {
                output[count++] = i;
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note, this will remove *all* instances of `item` from the input array rather than just one.