# How to remove a user entered value from an array?

Tags: java, windows

The user enters a value, and it is told that we are to remove the value, and print the newly created array. 
How do i write that code? It is supposed to be in that method removeValue.
Can you also explain how it works.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayHandler {
  public static void main(String[]args)
  {

    int[] array= new int[5]; // populates Array with 5 numbers
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) // creates the 5 random numbers
    array[i]=(int)(Math.random()*5000);
    printList(array); // prints Array
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Sum: " + calculateSum(array));
    System.out.println("Max: " + findMax(array));
    System.out.println("Minimum: " + findMin(array));
    System.out.println("Value: " + search(array));
  }
  public static void printList(int[] nums)
  {
    for(int i=0; i<nums.length;i++) {
      System.out.print(nums[i] + " "); 
  }
  }
  public static int calculateSum(int[] nums)
  {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
    {
      sum = sum + nums[i];
    }
    return sum;
  }
  public static int findMin(int[] nums)
  {
    int min = nums[0];
    for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
    {
      if(nums[i] < min)
         min=nums[i];
         }
return min;
}
  public static int findMax(int[] nums)
  {
    int max=nums[0];
    for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
    {
      if(nums[i] > max)
        max=nums[i];
    }
    return max;
  }
  public static int search(int[] nums)
  {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What value do you want?");
    int value = keyboard.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
    {
      if(nums[i] == value)
      return i;
   }
    return -1;
  }
  public static int removeValue (int[] nums)
  {
    int[] array = new array[array.charAt(value) - array.charAt(value)];
    if(nums[i] == i)
      return array;
    else
      return -1;
  }    
}
```

Comment: Please don't post *all* your code. Just post the part that you are having trouble with. What approaches have you tried to remove the element from the array?

Comment: `int[] array = new array[array.charAt(value) - array.charAt(value)]` will return array[0]. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing an element from an Array (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642897/removing-an-element-from-an-array-java)

Comment: `removeValue` makes no sense.  Where does `i` come from?  What does it mean to do `charAt` on an array?  How does `array` get a value before you define it?  If you're going to remove an element, isn't the size of the new array `nums.length - 1`?

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered: [Removing an element from an Array (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642897/removing-an-element-from-an-array-java)

If you want to use only arrays, view this answer: [Removing an element from an Array (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642897/removing-an-element-from-an-array-java#answer-644764)

Answer (score -1):

```
public static String removeValue (int[] nums)
{

int i = search(nums);

nums[i] = nums[i] - nums [i];

if(nums[i] == 0)
{
    return Arrays.toString(nums);
}
else return "invalid";
}
```

This will work and instead of calling the search method in your main, call the removeValue method and pass it the array.

Comment: how is this not useful?? It fixes the issue perfectly unless I am misunderstanding the assignment.