# I am trying to sort an array via heapSort and its not working

Tags: java, heap, heapsort

For some reason, my sortByDuration method will not let me call my remove method to print out the items in my heap as they are being deleted. The purpose of this is just to sort the heap; it really doesn't matter that I am deleting it.

```
public static Song[] sortByDuration(Song[] songs)//sorts the heap
{
    for(int i=size;i>0;i--)
        System.out.print(songs.remove()+" ");
    return songs;
}
```

and this is my remove method

```
public Song remove()//removes
{
    Song retVal = peek();

    heap[0] = heap[size-1];
    heap[size-1] = null;
    size--;

    bubbleDown();

    return retVal;
}
```

the error is in the print statement of my remove method
Thanks guys

Comment: The error would be a nice addition to your question

Comment: Print out the value of size before you run that for loop. It is probably 0

Comment: its a compilation error, cannot invoke remove() on the array type song

Comment: Been an *awful* lot of questions about this homework assignment today... is there a contest going on or something?

Comment: @J.Steen for me, seems like there are lot of people that cannot implement a heapsort...

Comment: should be:
 System.out.print(songs[i].remove()+" ");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call the method `remove()` on an array of objects. Arrays in Java do not have such a method.

For your code to work properly, you will need to change the way you remove the objects from your `songs` array. Maybe you want to take a look at "[Removing an element from an Array (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642897/removing-an-element-from-an-array-java)" question here in SO.

You may also have missed to index your elements (to access only the `i`-th element instead of the entire array), and the statement you wanted to write was

```
        System.out.print(songs[i].remove()+" ");
```