# How do I remove an element within an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic

Could someone give me a very elementary example in doing this?

I'm trying to write a method that takes something looks inside an array and remove a specific element from within the array at index i.

Comment: Do you actually need to remove the element, or can you simply mark it as deleted by using a certain value (i.e. a "soft" delete)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing an element from an Array (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642897/removing-an-element-from-an-array-java)

Comment: Don't use an array for this. If you want a "dynamic" array, use the best tool -- an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the array item to null, or use ArrayUtils'

`array = ArrayUtils.removeElement(array, element)`

you could also fill it with a blank value of the array type.
This is a very abstract question with many answers, but google is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

> Arrays have fixed size so deleting an element would be a costly
>   operation.
>
> Method 1: create a new array of size length -1 and copy all elements
>   except the one you want to delete.
>
> Method 2: Use ArrayList instead of arrays.