# Need help Removing Element from an Ordered Array using For Loop

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to remove a single element from an array. This is what I have tried so far:

```
for (int i = pos + 1; i < currentSize; i++) 
    values[???] = values[i];
currentSize--;
```

I'm so confused on what goes inside the `[???]`
If anyone can help I would really really appreciate it.

Comment: I think you're looking for `i - 1`.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? You have some array called `values`, with size - lets say 5 - and you want what? To have it shrink to 4 elements? Or do you want to replace one value in your array?

Comment: Remove the element and shrink the array by one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing an element from an Array (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642897/removing-an-element-from-an-array-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are not very kind in nature, as they can't be resized. As soon as you have learned about objects and generics you will pretty much stop using arrays and transition to `Collection`s. But for now, you'll have to create a new (smaller) array and copy all - but one - value. I will keep it very basic, so you learn the most:

```
int indexToRemove = 3;

Object[] newArray = new Object[values.length - 1];

for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
    if (i < indexToRemove) {
        newArray[i] = values[i];
    } else {
        newArray[i] = values[i + 1];
    }
}
```

I didn't know of which type your `values` are, so I just took `Object`. You may want to replace that.

Answer (score 0):

The ??? In this case indicates the index of the array where you wish to get the value from. If you have an array A with elements 5, 10, 15, and 20 then each of the elements can be retrieved with their index. I.e. the index for 5 is 0, for 10 its 1.

An array of size n will have n-1 elements in it due to zero indexing (A[0] is the first element).