# How to remove an object from arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I implemented both `add()` and `remove()` methods from my `ArrayList` Class.

```
    public void add(Object obj) {
        if(data.length - currentSize <= 5) {
            increaseListSize();
        }
        data[currentSize++] = obj;
    }

    public Object remove(int index){
        if(index < currentSize){
            Object obj = data[index];
            data[index] = null;
            int tmp = index;
            while(tmp < currentSize){
                data[tmp] = data[tmp+1];
                data[tmp+1] = null;
                tmp++;
            }
            currentSize--;
            return obj;
        } else {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }    
    }
```

However, I don't know how to remove the specific index of my `ArrayList` of `members`.

```
                if(temp[0].equals("ADD")) {
                    memberList.add(member);
                    fileOut.writeLine(member.toString());
                    fileLog.writeLine("New member " + member.toString() + " was succesfully added");

                }
                **else if(temp[0].equals("REMOVE")) {
               //memberList.remove(index)

                }**
            }
```

Is there any suggestion of how should I get to remove the index of an object of  the `memberList`? Can I modify my `remove()` method so that I could directly remove the object instead?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642897/removing-an-element-from-an-array-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing an element from an Array (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642897/removing-an-element-from-an-array-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to overload the existing remove-method with one that takes an Object-parameter. In the method body you have to iterate through the objects of the list and determine the index of the passed object. Then the existing remove-method is called using the previously determined index to remove the corresponding object.

The following implementation removes the **first** occurrence of the specified object from the list. The removed object is returned. If the list does not contain the object **null** is returned.

```
public Object remove(Object obj){
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i] == obj) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (index != -1) {
        return remove(index);
    }
    return null;
}
```