# Delete element from Array directly

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections

I have an array like below:

```
PersonClass[] person= {
            new PersonClass("90234234434", "John", "Smith", 22, "Street 22/5", 10//this is priority from 0 up to 10),
            ...
            ...
    };
```

Then I search for a security ID that starts from 98

```
for(int n = 0; n < person.length; n++)
    {
        if(person[n].getSecId().contains("98"))
        {
            System.out.println(person[n].toString());s
            //delete this object from person array
        }
    }
```

Now my question is: Can I delete this object directly from the array, if not how can I convert it into collection eg. ArrayList.

Comment: Set it to `null`. GC will delete it by itself.

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642897/removing-an-element-from-an-array-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove objects from an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112503/how-do-i-remove-objects-from-an-array-in-java)

Comment: by the way.. if you want to check if ID starts with 98 you should use `startsWith()` method

Comment: A remark: If you want to delete `Person`s which `secId`s start with, some string, use [`String#startsWith(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)) instead of [`String#contains(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)).

Comment: Every other post on stackoverflow didn't solve my problem. I want to delete it straight from array, not from collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Java 8 you can use :

```
person = Arrays.stream(person)
           .filter(p -> !p.getSecId().startsWith("98")) // note the not ! here
           .toArray(PersonClass[]::new);
```

Another thing :

> Then I search for security ID that starts from 98

in this case you can replace contains with `startsWith` to just check the first characters.

Comment: I'm using Java 8 and that solve my problem thanks. Could you please, explain a little bit how it exactly work?

Comment: @G.Dawid the idea is simple you just need to filter the secId which not start with "98" then collect the result as an array and assign the result to your first array

Comment: @G.Dawid You want to use `filter`. The `dropWhile` operation does something completely different.

Comment: @G.Dawid, StuartMarks is correct, after I read my answer I realize that the second way is not correct in your case

Comment: @StuartMarks you are correct, I totally forgot the `dropWhile` utilities

Answer (score 0):

You could use the static method java.util.Arrays.asList() to covert an array into an ArrayList

Comment: This is poorly documented, but the List returned by Arrays.asList() does not support structural (add or remove) operations. It and its iterator only support replacing existing elements.